"Knox Deployment" : what does this screen want me to do, exactly?
I recently purchased a Samsung A23 and today I "factory reset" it. The first screen that appears during first boot (after "factory reset") says the following:

Knox Deployment
Samsung's Knox Enrolment Service enables you to enrol your phone with
a company. Select an option below to start enrolment.
Bluetooth: Enrol by pairing your phone with your IT admin's device. By
proceeding, you agree to allow access to your phone's location.
Wi-Fi Direct: Enrol through a Wi-Fi Direct connection to your IT
admin's device. By proceeding, you agree to allow access to your
phone's location.
QR code: Enrol by scanning a QR code. By proceeding, you agree to
allow access to the camera.


I have never enrolled with Knox before, and I can do nothing with my IT admin's device because I have no IT admin.
I am confused by the wording used on this screen. Does this screen mean that my phone has previously been enrolled with Knox i.e. that I need to know the credentials of the previous enrolment for me to be able to continue to use the phone?
Or is this screen trying to get me to enrol my phone with Knox for the first time?
TIA.

I bought it as a new phone, online from O2's website Am I sure the phone is not stolen? I'm not sure of anything anymore! (I'm reasonably certain I still know my first name, but only reasonably certain!)

Normally such Mobile Device Management prepared devices can not be bought by end users, they are bought by companies often in bulk of 100 or 1000 devuces. But the Samsung webpage mentions that there is a Knox enrollment app that would allow an enrollment afterward may be even using a consumer device. Not sure how to reverse this. BTW what accounts had you installed before the factory reset? Possibly an account that is related to your work?

I only had personal accounts on this phone - nothing work related at all. I'll drop it into an O2 branch asap (hopefully this weekend) - I'm looking forward to hearing their opinion. I'll keep you updated...
